# Search folders in Outlook 2013 not updating on start

Tags: windows-8, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I reorganized my email and added 3 more .pst data files (removing a few more older ones).
The problem is that the only Search Folders updating on start are only the main inbox ones (the only data file from previous setup) and the rest I have to access them every time to make their first update. After that first access they are updated in real time.
Windows 8.1 / Outlook 2013

Can someone tell me what do I miss?

Comment: I just wanted to state that I'm having the same issue, so I'm curious if this ever got resolved by yourself directly and you didn't answer here?  I don't want to open a new question if possible.